# Is there any way to display "Next Steps" directions after running "compose require"?

Tags: php, composer-php

I have built a composer package that requires the user to run `vendor/phpexperts/dockerize/install.php`.

Is there any way for composer to actually tell them they need to do this? Or must they read the README?

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way that works for all installations, as there is no way to react to an installation in core features. For example, there's a long discussion about this in https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1193 where the creator of Composer declines to automatically run scripts from depending packages due to security concerns - I assume the same argumentation would follow if there was a feature request to run scripts in direct dependencies directly after an installation.

But there might be workarounds. Symfony Flex is able to run scripts after an installation, and there's a contrib repository where you could add your installation scripts.

Answer (score 0):

One "hacky" way to do this would be to use the ["suggest"](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#suggest) key in `composer.json`. Every key-value pair in "suggest" takes the format:

```
"<suggested-package>": "<message>"
```

The package names don't seem to be validated currently, so you can put anything in there.

When you run `composer install`, the suggests are shown as:

```
<vendor>/<package> suggests installing <suggested-package> (<message>)
```

The `(<message>)` part is left out if the message is an empty string.